# CompareTo method not working, it won't get AlbumName from the Album class- IComparable issue I think

Tags: c#, error-handling, icomparable

I'm trying to get my CompareTo method to from Artist class to work, however it won't get AlbumName from the Album class. I'm pretty sure it's an issue with IComparable on the Album class. Please help with code specific answers, thankyou.

Error   1   'Assignment.Album' does not implement interface member 'System.IComparable.CompareTo(object)'

Album Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Assignment
{
    class Album : IComparable
    {
        public string albumName;

        public Album(string albumName)//constructors
        {
            this.albumName = albumName;

        }

        public string AlbumName
        {
            get { return albumName; }
            set { albumName = AlbumName; }
        }
    }
}
```

Artist Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace Assignment
{
    public class Artist : IComparable
    {
        private String name;
        int members = 4;//default number of members
        //string albumName;

        LinkedList<Artist> albums = new LinkedList<Artist>();

        public override string ToString()//to make my own toString method
        {
            return ("Name: " + name + "Number of Members: " + members);
        }

        public Artist(string name, int members)//constructors
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.members = members;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = Name; }
        }

        public int Members
        {
            get { return members; }
            set { members = value; }
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Artist) //compare by name
            {
                Artist other = (Artist)obj;
                return name.CompareTo(other.name);//artist name
            }
            if (obj is string) //compare against list of album titles
            {
                string other = obj.ToString();

                    if (obj.Equals(name.AlbumName))
                        return 0;

                return -1;
            }
            else
                return -999;  //indicates can’t make a comparison    
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to compare an artist against an album or a string? Fundamentally it's pretty odd for an `IComparable` implementation to compare one type against a different one. (Indeed, these days you'd usually implement `IComparable<Artist>` instead.)

Comment: And of course the compiler is entirely right - your `Album` class *doesn't* have a `CompareTo` method.

Comment: And *why* would you name a variable which is a list of *artists* as `albums`? Artists and albums are different things! Fundamentally I think you probably need to take a step back, work out what you're actually trying to achieve, and start again.

Comment: It's for a form- as part of the assignemnt we were told to make Album a separate class to Artist, rather than include it in there. In the form it's supposed to prevent the same Artist, or Album from being entered twice. This works for artist, but not Album.

Comment: I never said that `Artist` and `Album` should be the same class. But you shouldn't use `IComparable` to compare the two. Instead, you should extract all the names from both artists and albums into a `HashSet<string>`.

Comment: I appreciate your help, however we are supposed to be able to complete this part of the project using IComparable.

Comment: f your assignment calls for `IComparable`, then both classes should implement it.  Really though, `HashSet<string>` is the appropriate tool here, for future reference.

Comment: @Nick: Then *either* you've misinterpreted the use of `IComparable` for this part of the project *or* your teachers are sadly misguided :(

Answer (score 2):

The error message you post says that there is no Compare(object) method in your Album class.  Your code confirms that.  So... add one!

EDIT

OK, let's break it down.  You're clearly learning a lot, and trying lots of new stuff.  That's great.  It helps to have a solid idea both of your goals and of your tools, so let's talk about those.

Based on your comments, it's clear that you are intending to use `IComparable` for ordering and guaranteeing uniqueness in a form.  Generally `IComparable` isn't used for uniqueness, but you have a 'business requirement' to use it, so...

Let's talk about the tools at hand.  I think you just need to understand what `IComparable` means.  It means that the class implementing it has a natural ordering, like numbers or (ahem) names in a list.  Specifically, it guarantees three non-exceptional outcomes:

1. `this` is "less than" the argument: return some number less than 0
2. `this` is "greater than" the argument: return some number greater than 0
3. `this` has the same order as the argument: return 0.

That's it.

Things that use the interface tend to be collections that sort items.  They use that number to guide their sorting.  The only thing they care about is if the number is less than, greater than, or equal to zero.  The return number doesn't mean anything else, so returning `-999` as you do isn't going to tell anybody anything useful.  If whatever you have truly is not able to be compared, the right thing to do is to throw an exception.

So hopefully you have some idea how `IComparable` is used, let's talk about how it's usually implemented.

Have you heard of generics?  It's a fundamental feature of .NET that will guide the compilation and execution of your code based on types.  If an interface is generic, that means you can implement is multiple times, specifying a different type each time.  There is a generic version of `IComparable`: `System.IComparable<T>`.  If your class needs to compare strings, it should implement `IComparable<string>` as well as `IComparable<Artist>` or what-have-you.  If you do so, your class will look something like this:

```
public class Artist : IComparable<string>, IComparable<Artist>
{
    // your code here

    public int Compare(string name)
    {
        // your code here
    }

    public int Compare(Artist artist)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

If you are working with an older technology like Windows Forms that expects the non-generic `IComparable` interface, you can implement that, too, like so:

```
public int Compare(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return -1; // maybe you want to throw an exception instead?
    if (obj is string) return Compare((string) obj);
    if (obj is Artist) return Compare((Artist) obj);

    throw new ArgumentException("wtf, unexpected type");
}
```

Finally, why is your list of artists in the Album class?  Think about where the check for uniqueness needs to happen.  It happens when the user types *in the form*, right?  Don't you think that the list belongs there, too?

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, I tried adding one in before and it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Wow thanks for taking the time to explain all of that stuff, maybe if I explain the assignment in greater detail it will put what I'm trying to do into context. We should have a form that uses an AVL tree and allows the user to add, remove, edit an artists details- this includes name, albums and number of members. We have been told to make album a separate class, which should contain album names and release date (which I intend to do later). Once in the form we should be able to search for the artists, or album names in order to view their details and update them.

Comment: No worries, hope it helps.  If other people have better answers, it might help them if you update your question with that information, instead of leaving it semi-hidden down here!

Comment: Did this help resolve your issue?  If so, it's good form to mark it as an answer ;)